# ofstream : can't convert to ofstream&

Tags: c++

I write a code in order to write prime number in a file, and after that I write another function in order to part the work in many threading. But my problem is the compiler write me an error

```
error C2664: 'void (int,int,std::ofstream &)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 
'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'std::ofstream &'.
```

But my problem is that I don't understand what the error says and where I do a thing that is forbidden.

This is my code:

```
void writePrimesToFile(int begin, int end, ofstream& file)
{
    int i, j, prime = 1;

    for (i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
        for (j = begin; i <= end / 2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = 0;
            } else {
                file << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N)
{
    double startTimer, stopTimer;

    startTimer = clock();
    thread* arr = new thread[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int start = begin;
        int finish = N;
        arr[i] = thread(writePrimesToFile, start, finish, ref(filePath));
        start = finish;
        finish += N;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i].join();
    }
    stopTimer = clock();
    cout << "The time that takes is: " <<
            double(stopTimer - startTimer) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're passing a reference to a `std::string` object to your thread function, which wants a `std::ofstream` reference (clearly stated in the message). That will not work very well.

Comment: Oh, and you have a memory leak to. Why don't you use `std::vector` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Where I have a memory leak ? Can you explain more !

Comment: Don't do this; `thread* arr = new thread[N];` do this `std::vector<std::thread> arr;` followed by `arr.emplace_back(writePrimesToFile, start, finish... etc);`

Comment: @Galik Where is my N in your example of vector

Comment: You are also going to need to synchronize access to your file somehow (pass a reference to a `std::mutex`?).

Comment: @RonyCohen In my example `N` is not needed because `emplace_back` adds a new element to the vector each time it is called.

Comment: With the vector you don't really need `N` any more. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is *dynamic* and will grow and shrink as needed. As for the memory leak, every `new` must be matched with a `delete`, and every `new[]` must be matched with a `delete[]`.

Comment: @RonyCohen To join the threads do this: `for(auto&& thread: arr) thread.join();`

Comment: @Galik What is the auto is &&. Can you explain more ?

Comment: @RonyCohen Its a reference to the thread in the vector. I used `&&` when I could have just used `&` out of habit (it  works in more situations). So `for(auto& thread: arr)` basically iterates through all the threads in the vector giving you a *reference* to each one that you can use to `join()`. It is like saying ***for each thread in arr*** *`join()` that thread*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thread function expects third parameter as `std::ofstream` reference, you are trying to bind reference to `std::string` instead. So create `std::ofstream` before loop and pass it:

```
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N)
{
    double startTimer, stopTimer;

    std::ofstream file( filePath );
    // check that file is opened

    startTimer = clock();
    ...
         arr[i] = thread(writePrimesToFile, start, finish, ref(file));
```

you dynamically allocate array of thread by `new[]` and do not have `delete[]` at the end of your function hence the memory leak. It would be easier and cleaner to use `std::vector<std::thread>` instead:

```
 //thread* arr = new thread[N];
 std::vector<std::thread> arr( N ); // replace with this and you do not need to touch anything else
```

Comment: Why with vector I don't have to clean the memory like free or delete ?

Comment: @RonyCohen because instance of `std::vector` would be automatic variable in scope of your function, destructor of it cleans resources vector allocates.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: @RonyCohen you need to read about object lifetime, construction/destruction, RAII etc, topic is too big to explain it in a comment.

Comment: @RonyCohen for short in example above I created instance of `std::vector` which creates N threads inside. When `arr` would be destroyed and the end of scope (end of your function) resources would be released automatically. When you allocate manually with `new[]` you must destroy manually with `delete[]` (or use a smart pointer)